# Proving that: $[\mu(tA+(1-t)B)]^{1/n}\ge t[\mu(A)]^{1/n}+(1-t)[\mu(A)]^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be the standard Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$ How can I  show that the maps defined on Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra by $$A\mapsto[\mu(A)]^{1/n}$$ is concave in the sense that

$$[\mu(tA+(1-t)B)]^{1/n}\ge t[\mu(A)]^{1/n}+(1-t)[\mu(B)]^{1/n}$$

for every $t\in[0,1]$. Where $$A+B =\{a+b: a\in A,b\in B\}$$ stand for the Minskowski sum of $A$ and $B.$